# Installing imod_4.7.15_RHEL6-64_CUDA6.0.csh in ubuntu

Tags: csh

Can anyone help me with the installing of imod_4.7.15_RHEL6-64_CUDA6.0.csh software.imod is a image software,which I have downloaded from http://bio3d.colorado.edu/imod/download.html.I have extracted the file using zip-unzip command.but I am unable to run it as a software.

Answer (score 0):

Run in the terminal:

```
csh -f imod_4.7.15_RHEL6-64_CUDA6.0.csh
```